# Can I change the ownership of all the files of a specific user?

Tags: linux, centos, bash, shell, shell-scripting

Is there a way to recursively find all files owned by a user and change them to another user/group in Gnu/Linux?

I assume there must be some magic one liner but my command line wizardry skills are not up to that :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `find` command with the `-user` option.  Something like:

`find / -user john`

will eventually turn up all files owned by user "john".

If you want to change their ownership (I would run the `find` without execution to make sure you have the list you want), then something like:

`find / -user john -exec chown harry {} \;`

will do it.

Comment: I usually use UID and run `chown harry:harry` if I need to make sure the group membership is right, too. But that depends heavily on the application here.

Comment: It actually wouldn't work for me unless I used the UID. The UID can be found in /etc/passwd

Answer (score 7):

This is late, but today I stumbled across this question
because my `rsync` doesn't have the `--usermap` option.

My `chown` (v. chown (GNU coreutils) 8.13) offers a built-in recurse (`-R`) and a `--from` option so your (and my) problem could've also been solved using

```
chown -R --from=john harry /
```

---

More specifically I'm migrating a server from OpenSuse to debian, and the user and group of apache2 differ between the distributions. In OpenSuse its user `wwwrun (id:30)` and group `www (id:8)`, in debian `www-data (id: 33)` for both.
After I copied the files using

```
rsync -az /path/to/files me@debian:/path/to/
```

I used

```
chown -R --from=30 33 /path/to/files/
chown -R --from=:8 :33 /path/to/files/
```

on the target (debian) machine.

---

Note: `rsync  version 3.1.0  protocol version 31` has the above mentioned `--usermap` so if I had that I could've done all three steps with one command on the source machine:

```
rsync -az --usermap=30:33 --groupmap=8:33 /path/to/files root@debian:/path/to/
```

Comment: I prefer this one, especially for the option to change group as well. A `find -exec` one liner for me is a last resort, just before doing things manually. (Also, I hate writing `{} \;`, but this is personal)